# Stop in Close and Open userforms _VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I created two forms. Pressing the button 1 opens the form number 2. By closing the form number 2, the form number 1 is displayed. But this action is only done once and it stops for the second time and almost does not work. Where does the code have a problem?

*code Userform1:*

```
Private Sub ShowUserform2_Click()
  UserForm1.Hide
  Unload UserForm1
  UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

*Code userform2:*

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
  UserForm2.Hide
  Unload UserForm2
  UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "almost does not work"?  I'm not entirely sure why you're trying to `Hide` and `Unload` a form from inside its `Terminate` event - that event fire *in response to* being unloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip the `formName.Hide` lines.  They are unnecessary.

After the `Unload formName` statements add:

```
Set formName = Nothing
```

Also, make the `otherForm.Show` line precede the above two lines.

Comment: [Setting the default instances of the forms to `Nothing` after they are unloaded is not necessary.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/04/28/when-are-you-required-to-set-objects-to-nothing/)

Comment: After I submitted the answer, I realized the reason the OP probably was having a problem was because they were performing the other form show -after- trying to hide and unload the form, and you're right, not only is it probably not necessary, in VBA it probably doesn't even work, especially if called from within the form you're unloading.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

*code Userform1:*

```
Private Sub ShowUserform2_Click()
    UserForm1.Hide
    UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

*Code userform2:*

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Nader! Your code will only be repeated once. For the second time error "Run-time error '400'". - @Nader Nagazi

Comment: Can you share your file with me?

Comment: My file was exactly the text of your code and there was nothing superfluous. The correct answer is given by _Bill Hileman_. Thanks for the time you left.